# Winget The manifest version is higher than supported

Tags: windows, winget

Just install the windows package manager and start to install software.

I receive this error every time I try to install any software.

```
An unexpected error occurred while executing the command:
Unsupported ManifestVersion: 1.0.0
0x8a150007 : Cannot process manifest. The manifest version is higher than supported. Please update the client.
```

[image]

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just update your Winget client with the latest version : https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases

Enjoy